# How to use trudepth IphoneX front camera to detect objects?

Tags: swift, xcode4, object-detection

I want to do an app that uses the front camera to detect objects and the distance from the phone to the object. However, to use the front camera trueDepth all the options available are using AR face tracking. Is there any other way to use the front camera?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata - this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Matic I think I will use this for the back 2 cameras, to get the distance of the image. I will use CoreML for object detection. Thanks